# Lodash - Fastest way to filter by minimum difference between values

Tags: node.js, lodash

I need to filter the array based on the minimum difference between two consecutive numbers. The result should also not have any duplicates and include min and max values. here are some examples.

```
x1 = [1,2,5,6,3,4,3,3,2,2] and delta = 3, then the result = [1,4,6]
x1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] and delta = 2, then the result = [1,3,5,7,9,10]
```

I can use orderBy and reduce higher-order functions to achieve this, but I wanted to know the fastest way to do this, as I need to do it on an array with 100k length.

Comment: [1,4,6]? 6-4=2?